"Export value" checkbox has been ignored when doing Import for a managed solution on PROD power platform environment
I have 2 environments inside Power Platform:-

Dev

PROD


Where inside the Dev environment i set all the environment variables as follow with the "Export value" checkbox turned off:-

I usually do the following which was working well (last time i did an export/import was 3 months ago):-

Export the solution from Dev as managed solution

Import the solution to PROD using the Update option, as follow:-



where things were straightforward, as all the environments variables inside the Dev, have the "Export" checkbox unchecked, so the environment variables inside the imported solution should AUTOMATICALLY use the setting inside PROD when doing the Import inside the PROD, without the need to reconfigure them.
But starting from last week, when i do the Import inside the PROD, all the environment variables referencing SharePoint lists will appear inside the Import wizard and they all have the GUID of the list inside DEV, so I have to manually reconfigure them, where I have around 80 SharePoint lists.
Here is how the Import wizard will look like, first I got that a SharePoint connection need to be reconfigured, although I did not change it on Dev or on PROD: -

After that when I click on "Next", I were asked to reconfigure all the environment variables representing SharePoint lists and libraries, as follow: -

any advice what is going on? why i need to reconfigure the environment variables?
And I noted that even when i select all the lists representing the PROD environment variables and the import got completed, the modified dates for those environment variables will be 2 months ago, so seems they did not get affected by the selection,, so is this a bug inside the import wizard and can this be solved?

Thanks
